# custom field field in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

i have a test and i have to create a table that has these fields :

`name , date , price , customField.`

Custom fields have a title and a list of key values.
example can have a product “House” with a customField called “House Fields” and
this field has a list of key values such as “Type” => “Apartment”, “Rooms”=> 5
etc

How can i implement this `customField` using PostgreSQL

Comment: Read about CREATE TYPE

Answer (score 2):

I would store this dynamic information in a `jsonb` column

```
create table the_table
(
  name text not null, 
  "date" date not null,
  price numeric not null
  custom_fields jsonb
);
```

Then you can do something like this.

```
insert into the_table (name, "date", price, custom_fields)
values 
  ('House', current_date, 42, '{"Type": "appartment", "Rooms: 5}'),
  ('Shirt', current_date, 24, '{"Color": "blue", "Size": "XL"}');
```

---

Btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column. Not only because it's also a keyword, but more importantly because it doesn't really document what kind of date that is. Creation date? Expiration Date? Sales start date? Sales end date?

Comment: it is creation date and there is another date field (duration) and and whenever the API is called, it will return the products that are supposed to show up at the current time.

Comment: if i use jsonb how can i modify on it (add delete edit)

Comment: @user10596155: sure there are [many functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to manipulate JSON data.

Comment: But can i create the customField using sequelize ?

Comment: @user10596155 [Yes, sequelize supports PostgreSQL's JSONB type](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/other-data-types.html#jsonb--postgresql-only-). Keep in mind that the details of that implementation deserve a new thread.

Comment: Excuse me .. for some reasons (i dont know why and dont have the time to fix ) but postgreSQL didnt installed .. i have mySQL using xampp .. it work the same way right ? Like no difference i can use sequelize and create ```customField```

Comment: @user10596155: no idea. I don't use MySQL. If you want an answer for MySQL you should ask a question for Postgres